# Определить входит ли точка координат в радиус окружности

Tags: javascript, jquery, геолокация

Нужно определить входит ли пользователь в радиус области, есть точка широты и долготы Санкт-Петербурга 59.93428, 30.3351 и радиус действия например 100 км, мы получаем данные пользователя по HTML5 Geolocation API, нужно понять входит ли он в область СПО?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы определить дистанцию между двумя координатами, можно воспользоваться функцией:

```js
function geoDistance(lat1,lon1,lat2,lon2) {

    // a = sin²(Δφ/2) + cos(φ1)⋅cos(φ2)⋅sin²(Δλ/2)
    // tanδ = √(a) / √(1−a)
    // see mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/51879.html for derivation

    const R = 6371e3, π = Math.PI;
    const { sin, cos, atan2 } = Math;
    const φ1 = lat1 * π / 180, λ1 = lon1 * π / 180;
    const φ2 = lat2 * π / 180, λ2 = lon2 * π / 180;
    const Δφ = φ2 - φ1,        Δλ = λ2 - λ1;

    const a = sin(Δφ/2)**2 + cos(φ1) * cos(φ2) * sin(Δλ/2)**2;
    const c = 2 * atan2(a**.5, (1-a)**.5);
    const d = R * c;

    return d;
};

console.log('Расстояние в метрах =', 
             geoDistance(59.93428,30.3351, 55.75222,37.61556));
```

Comment: Спасибо, вот кто то заморочился же